# Specify xacro properties in launch file

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, xacro, ros-gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am working on ros-fuerte-gazebo. I have a world in which I want to spawn doors to different rooms.

Is there a way to specify the values for `<xacro:property>` tags in launch file ? I want to use a single `*.urdf.xacro` file using different values for the same property. Is it possible ?

For eg.:
In door.urdf.xacro

```
<xacro:property name = room value = "workroom" />
<link name = "${room}_door">
....
```

I would like to specify the value "workroom" for the property room in the launch file so that I can use the same `*.urdf.xacro` file for all the rooms in my gazebo world (kitchen, bedroom etc..). I know I can use TinyXML but it will be easier and simpler if I can specify the properties in launch file. Or is there any other way out ?

Thanks!

PS: I know this is more a ros question than a gazebo question. I am posting here hoping some gazebo enthusiast would help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2117/specify-xacro-properties-in-launch-file/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/247/prasanna.kumar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/38956/pass-parameters-to-xacro-in-launch-file/

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) with karma: 138 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1